# Installing gnuplot with Lua-Tikz terminal on Mac Os X

Tags: macos, lua, gnuplot, tikz

I'm on mac os X and I have `gnuplot` installed via MacPorts.

I want to be able to use the Lua-Tikz terminal (which is kind of present, I can find some `gnuplot-tikz.lua` files) but I can't. How do I enable `gnuplot` to use the `lua tikz` terminal?

I'm willing to uninstall and reinstall `gnuplot`if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer was given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/where-to-find-the-gnuplot-lua-tikz-terminal/16540#16540)